# common root assigning to all child and subchild.group all directly and indirectly related records using python pandas

Tags: python, record-linkage

I am trying to group all child and sub child entities(direct or indirect) associate with root node ID (root is the one which got created first based on date)

First Data can be generated here:

data = [['tom', 'hanks','2020-01-02 08:21:50.617','A198'], ['tommy', 'hanks','2020-01-02 06:21:50.617','A125'], ['tami', 'robert','2020-01-02 05:21:50.617','A456'],['robby', 'jones','2020-01-03 10:21:50.617','A566'],['robo', 'martin','2020-01-03 07:21:50.617','A778'],['tobi', 'profet','2020-01-03 11:21:50.617','A454'],['amber', 'serra','2020-01-02 04:21:50.617','A444'],['amana', 'kordos','2020-01-02 04:21:50.617','A387'],['amberosa', 'maria','2020-01-02 04:21:50.617','A777']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['First_name', 'Last_Name','Date_of_transaction','id'])

df['Date_of_transaction']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date_of_transaction'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

df=df.sort_values(by=['Date_of_transaction'])

df= df.reset_index(drop=True)
df

[image: df]

Another dataframe has left and right index with probability of match

prob=[[1,3,0.88],[1,4,0.82],[3,2,0.86],[5,2,0.85],[6,7,0.86],[9,7,0.86]]
prob_df = pd.DataFrame(prob, columns = ['left_index', 'right_index','probability'])
prob_df

[image: prob_df]

In this example 1 is linked with 3 and 4 .
3 is further linked with 2 and 2 is linked with 5. so i want to create a new dataframe which will have the original df with new column 'New_unique_ID'

[image: needed_Result_df]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you're looking for is a type of tree searching algorithm. 
To find the minimum value, I would recommend running the algorithm and creating a dictionary of each left_index and then appending any unique index value that is connected to any of its children to form a set of values and then sort those values and choose the first one as the New_Unique_ID.

```
{1:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
2:[1, 2, 3, 5]
ect...
```

Creating a tree searching algorithm for your purpose is not straight forward and would be difficult to explain if I just wrote it for you and handed it off. Therefor its probably best if you designed it yourself so here is the wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_tree.
[image: Node tree]